# Compound indexes in MongoDB efficiency unclear

Tags: mongodb, indexing

Im looking for a structure to save userdata for a discord bot.
The context is that i need a unique save for a user for each discord sever (aka. guild) he is on. 
Therefore neither userID nor guildID should be unique, but i could use them as compound index to quickly find users inside the users collection.

Is my train of thought correct until now?

My actual question is:

Which ID should be the first index its "sorted" by?
there are multiple hundred or thousand users per guild, but a single user is on about 1-5 guilds the bot is on.
Therefore first searching by guildID would make the amount of data to search in by userID somewhat smaller.
But first searching for userID would make the amount of data to search in by guildID even smaller.
Since the DB will search both indexes completely anyway, so step1 will be similarly quick for both, the second idea with first filtering by userID and then by guildID seems more efficient to me.

I'd like to know if my assumption seems viable, and if not, why not.
Or if there would be a better way that i haven't thought of.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Before consuming assumptions, its always better to check your query execution time, note it down, check explain object, apply indexes, again check for query execution time, note the difference and check explain object again to see any effect applied. Moreover your indexes should be targeting your `major` work on your application. In other words, you  keep indexes so as to optimize your query that takes the longest route!

Comment: thanks for the tip, but the thing is, i want to have this sorted before actually implementing it. of course, if there is no simple answer, i will just try it and compare performance at a later date, when numbers are high enough to atcually matter. (im at 60.000 users right now)

but concerning the major, i do believe the userid is the largest load because thats literally the only thing that defines the user and is *almost* unique, only that i save multiple version each one per guild

Comment: Fact is you know your requirement well, and you know how compound indexes can be really effective if chosen properly. Obvious hint is to figure out your `expensive` operation in your app and choose your index (single/compound/multikey) accordingly and if possible have a covered query at the very best. I will recommend you to read here: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/applications/indexes/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Compound indexes worked fine.
Still not big enough to see any difference in implementation of them, so i don't know about that.